# Why not able to call terminate method even program launched outside VS debugger?

Tags: c++, exception

I have written very simple program and expected to crash, and it crashes. Now, I have set terminate function, but it will not be called and program just crashed without calling this function.

I have test program both inside debugger/outside debugger, built in both debug/release mode, but showing same behaviour (at least no calling my terminate function). I am musing VS 2012 and Windows 10.

```
void func()
{
    cout<<"Aah you threw exception"<<endl;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    set_terminate(func); //setting terminate function 

    int *p = NULL;

    *p =11; 
    cout<<*p; //this will throw exception
}
```

Comment: Because no C++ exception was thrown?

Comment: @immibis Why C++ exception is not thrown, anyway terminate will be called, right? Am I missing something?

Comment: Dereferencing a nullptr will normally trigger a segmentation violation and not a C++ exception unless you have additional translation code set up. Unless you didn't include that part of the code the above code will simply crash with an appropriate signal and not go through any C++ error handler.

Comment: Why do you expect terminate to be called?

Comment: Because unhandled exception is thrown, and program has to exist, so by calling terminate it will exit.

Comment: You can use both SEH exceptions and C++ exceptions.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/swezty51.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C++ is not Java! A *signal* (or trap) can be generated by dereferencing a nullptr, but it is not automatically translated in C++ exception. On a POSIX compliant system, you can try to use the `signal` function to catch a signal as proposed by Throwaway Account 3 Million. On Windows, you can try to use the [C structured exception handling](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/swezty51.aspx).

If you don't, and still generate such a trap, the standard just defines that as an Undefined Behaviour, and it commonly just abort the program immediately, bypassing any `set_terminate`, `atexit` or whatever function you planned to be call on a *controlled* termination of your program.

Comment: `signal` is ANSI C, not POSIX, and works just fine on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Use `signal` to catch segmentation errors:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <signal.h>

using namespace std;

void func(int signal) {
   cerr << "Caught signal " << signal << endl;
}

int main() {
  signal(SIGSEGV, func);
  void (*p)() = NULL;
  p();
}
```